# How to get public key from .pfx

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2, pfx

I have Mycert.pfx file, I could extract private key using below code but not sure how to extract public key from .pfx file.

> private static X509Certificate2 LoadPrivateKey()
>    {
>       return new X509Certificate2(@"d:\myCert.pfx", "Pass123$");
>    }

Is it possible to get public key from .pfx, if so could you please share sample code of it.

Comment: I would suggest checking the [X509Certificate2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import?view=netframework-4.8) it has an Import method that gets the certificate from a cert or pfx.

Comment: Clearly there is a public key property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.publickey?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What version of a public key do you want? The public certificate DER/PEM? The public key blob DER/PEM? An instance of RSA (or whatever algorithm)?

Comment: Need to generate PEM format file